# SQL Query To Flip The Values And Make It A Field In A New Table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have this table below

[image]

How do I make the output like this

[image]

I did the output above using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    C.RefVal, 
    C.CalibrationEventID, 
    C1.Result As "Trial One", 
    C2.Result AS "Trial Two", 
    C3.Result AS "Trial Three", 
    C4.Result AS "Trial Four", 
    C5.Result AS "Trial Five" 
FROM CalibrationTrials AS C 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT RefVal, Result FROM CalibrationTrials WHERE CalibrationEventID = 'CAL000001' AND RefVal = '1.0010'AND TrialNo = 1) As C1 
ON C1.RefVal = C.RefVal
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT RefVal, Result FROM CalibrationTrials WHERE CalibrationEventID = 'CAL000001' AND RefVal = '1.0010'AND TrialNo = 2) As C2 
ON C2.RefVal = C.RefVal
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT RefVal, Result FROM CalibrationTrials WHERE CalibrationEventID = 'CAL000001' AND RefVal = '1.0010'AND TrialNo = 3) As C3 
ON C3.RefVal = C.RefVal
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT RefVal, Result FROM CalibrationTrials WHERE CalibrationEventID = 'CAL000001' AND RefVal = '1.0010'AND TrialNo = 4) As C4 
ON C4.RefVal = C.RefVal
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT RefVal, Result FROM CalibrationTrials WHERE CalibrationEventID = 'CAL000001' AND RefVal = '1.0010'AND TrialNo = 5) As C5 
ON C5.RefVal = C.RefVal

WHERE C.CalibrationEventID = 'CAL000001' AND C.RefVal = '1.0010'
ORDER BY C.RefVal, C.CalibrationEventID
```

Apparently with this query the output is only fixed to one RefVal which is '1.0010'

What would be the correct query to output image2 format for each RefVal of a CalibrationEventID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can use a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) clause for your query:

```
SELECT
  RefVal,
  CalibrationEventID,
  [1] AS [Trial One],
  [2] AS [Trial Two],
  [3] AS [Trial Three],
  [4] AS [Trial Four],
  [5] AS [Trial Five],
  [6] AS [Trial Six]
FROM CalibrationTrials
PIVOT (
  MAX(Result) FOR TrialNo IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) AS p
```

The above assumes that your table consists only of columns `RefVal, CalibrationEventID, 
TrialNo, Result`. If there are more columns in the table, you should first select these four separately, then apply PIVOT. Here:

```
SELECT
  RefVal,
  CalibrationEventID,
  [1] AS [Trial One],
  [2] AS [Trial Two],
  [3] AS [Trial Three],
  [4] AS [Trial Four],
  [5] AS [Trial Five],
  [6] AS [Trial Six]
FROM (
  SELECT
    RefVal,
    CalibrationEventID,
    TrialNo,
    Result
  FROM CalibrationTrials
) AS c
PIVOT (
  MAX(Result) FOR TrialNo IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) AS p
```

This is needed because a PIVOT query is essentially a special case GROUP BY query. All columns except `Result` take part in grouping *implicitly*. That's why you should get rid of those that are not needed in this kind of grouping.

And here's an alternative approach, without PIVOT:

```
SELECT
  RefVal,
  CalibrationEventID,
  MAX(CASE TrialNo WHEN 1 THEN Result END) AS [Trial One],
  MAX(CASE TrialNo WHEN 2 THEN Result END) AS [Trial Two],
  MAX(CASE TrialNo WHEN 3 THEN Result END) AS [Trial Three],
  MAX(CASE TrialNo WHEN 4 THEN Result END) AS [Trial Four],
  MAX(CASE TrialNo WHEN 5 THEN Result END) AS [Trial Five],
  MAX(CASE TrialNo WHEN 6 THEN Result END) AS [Trial Six]
FROM CalibrationTrials
GROUP BY
  RefVal,
  CalibrationEventID
```

Comment: You nailed it! But I used the alternative approach because with the pivot, it's not combined to one row. But with the alternative approach, only one row per RefVal. Is there a way doing this WITH the pivot table?

Comment: You must have shown incomplete table then. I assumed those were all columns the table had. If there are more, you should only select those that you need in the output You should select them *before pivoting*. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Okay what I did was I just grouped it by CalibrationEventID, and RefVal then used a MAX function for each trial. It did the same thing

Comment: Ah I see. Instead of the whole table just select the columns that will be used, right? Big thanks! Definitely clearer!